# Yii2 detailView attribute hints

Tags: yii2, attributes, hint, detailview

I have searched quite a lot, but haven't found any relevant info. Is there a way to add attribute hints in a 3rd column of the detailView?

Comment: You can extend this class and add third column.

Comment: How do we do that normally? I don't find anything about this topic.